# Trying to understand what a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ "looks" like

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the set
> $$
> E:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:0\leq x<1 \text{ and } x=1/n \text{ for some } n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2_\text{std.},
> $$
> where $\mathbb{R}^2_\text{std.}$ denotes the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My question is, what does this set "look" like? I understand the $0\leq x<1$ part; however, the $x=1/n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not making sense to me. It'd be helpful if someone could give me an example of a $p\in E$...

Comment: It is probably a typo... It should be something like $y = \frac 1n$. Can you post the exact original question?

Comment: It ... doesn't make sense.  Was $y_n$ defined early.

Comment: @PierreCarre: Correct! There was a note made that it should be $1/n$...

Comment: @fleablood: Should make sense now, fixed!

Comment: It looks like there are no constraints on $y$... so this is a bunch of vertical lines, at $x=1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots$. Unless there’s still a typo?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Ah okay, I see what the set is saying now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this (except where the vertical lines go on forever, instead of stopping at $\pm 1$.

[image: Lots of vertical lines]

These are lots of vertical lines, at each $x = 1/n$. The "wall of blue" on the left isn't a filled-in area --- it's just lots of close vertical lines. (Presumably this is being used in some sort of topology or real analysis counterexample, and it's the clustering near the line $x = 0$ that is leading to the counterexample part).

Comment: Very nice picture! Indeed it's being used in topology, though not as a counterexample but rather an example!

Comment: @D.Math A topologist from Canada once said to me that "counterexamples in topology" was a bad ttile for a book; it should have been "examples" instead. (But many examples have been discovered/invented to clarify or sharpen a conjecture, or illustrate the need for some condition in a theorem). He wanted a similar book for Boolean spaces BTW.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I agree with the Canadian topologist!